# Update ContentPlaceHolder with Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Say i have a MasterPage and two subpages, that are included through the ContentPlaceHolder.
Would it possible in AJAX to update the ContentPlaceHolder to change from 1 subpage to another?

And if so, are there any problems that i may encounter by using this type of interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ContentPlaceHolder` control, since it will not be rendered in your page.

Please use `div runat="server"` and use div id to load the ajax content

All the scripts in the page will work fine loaded via ajax. There are few scenarios it will break/conflict with the parent page script. In that case, you can use `iframe` and set a src attribute

Comment: Ahh of course. There's no DOM with CPH. So if i were to load a full functioning ASPX page inside a div, all the methods from that page would be working as intended?

Comment: That sounds amazing Murali. Do you think i would have to make all my subpages into User controls? Or would it be fine to keep them as aspx pages?

Comment: It would be better to have them as `.ascx` controls. Since they all will share a single page , i.e single `<head> and <body>`.

Comment: I'm guessing i would need a Update panel around my subpages, otherwise they would do a full postback and reset my interface.
I will try this with User controls. Thank you Murali :-)